# Rendering a scikit-learn DecisionTreeClassifier without the statistical metadata?

Tags: scikit-learn, graphviz

When using `sklearn.tree.export_graphiz()`, the exported tree nodes' labels contain statistical metadata such as `samples` and `value`.

I'd like to display a version of the tree to the user without this data. That is, only decision criteria like `length <= 7` and the classification itself will be displayed inside the node, nothing else.

Is that possible with `export_graphviz()`?  All I see is a keyword option to remove the `impurity` score, but none of the other statistics.

Comment: Looking through the source, there doesn't seem to be a configuration path to exclude these other statistics. I may have to post-process the DOT file data by parsing it and modifying the node labels to fit my requirements.

Comment: Well, there's a parameter `label` which when set to `None` will hide informative labels for impurity, etca t all nodes. Maybe that can help.

Comment: @VivekKumar: yes, thanks, that parameter exists. Unfortunately, it doesn't remove all the statistical metadata from the tree nodes, only the *labels* of the data, so it's not good enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option currently in the code. I had to get the string of the DOT file content (by providing the `out_file=None` argument), then process it through a simple DOT parser to remove all the metadata from the label.